# PhoneGap Android + jQuery mobile app does not scroll down

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a div that expands on touch, but when it expands it does not scroll to the expanded parts. I noticed this problem with Android devices running 2.3.3, this also happens on the older Iphone. I'm pretty sure it's a CSS problem.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Please post the code you are using, both conserning css, html and jQuery.

Comment: Code ? You must have tried something....

Comment: Hey, thanks for the respose, I have tried adding a overflow visible in the css for the content container and it kinda works. I am usung the jquary content class but here is the one that i am using in my css:.content_container.ui-content {
    padding: 15px;
     overflow : visible;
    
   } this is my container for the div that expands on touch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older android phones and older IOS does not support scrolling in divs: Use this function to scroll the element that you want to scroll:

```
function TouchScroll(elem){
```

// alert("listening");

```
var scrollStartPos=0;

elem.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {

                      scrollStartPos=this.scrollTop+event.touches[0].pageY;

                      // event.preventDefault();

                      },false);

elem.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {

                      this.scrollTop=scrollStartPos-event.touches[0].pageY;

                       event.preventDefault();

                      },false);
```

}